# jQuery click event isn't working

Tags: jquery

I have this simple jQuery click event, and for some reason it isn't working. The `$(document).ready(function() {});` works, and I can use alerts inside of that; however the actual click event isn't working.

Thanks in advance, and please be easy on me as I haven't had much experience with jQuery. Thanks! :)

Here's my code:

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("I can alert here");

    $("#the_id").click(function() {
        alert("I can't alert here");
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
// This is an <input> instead of a <button> because I will be creating an AJAX call later

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" id="the_id">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input` is of type `submit`. So, it will trigger a post back, which results in a page refresh. Use `event.preventDefault()` or change the type to `button`.

```
<input type="button" id="the_id" />
```

Or `event.preventDefault()`, after which you'll have to use ajax to send data to the server.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert("I can alert here");
    $("#the_id").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default action of submit
        alert("I can't alert here");
    });
});
```

---

Edit:
It should work as is. The problem might not be this.

Comment: so why does the alert not work? in the OPs case the alert need to work then the form has to submit... else how does your `e.preventDefault();` get called

Comment: @ArunPJohny once submit is clicked, immediately, it triggers a postback, so unless we prevent it, the event handler won't get called, because of the page refresh.

Comment: Like Arun said, if I have any problems with the AJAX call I'll report back

Comment: @mightyspaj3 glad to have helped. Also, put it in a separate question, instead of appending it to this.

Comment: then how does the `e.preventDefault();` gets called if the click ahndler itself is not working... now not relavent since OP said it is working

Comment: look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f7v6beop/1/) the alert is working without prevent default... then the form is getting submitted... how is that

Comment: @ArunPJohny it's working there. Perhaps they have some tweaking done?

Comment: @ArunPJohny no. I tried out in my system. It should work as OP has it. And you're right. Don't know why OP isn't getting an alert.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use

```
$("#the_id").submit(function() {
    // code will run before submitting form
});
```